# django-allauth: verifying email only on non social signup

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0, django-allauth

I'm using `django-allauth` plugin. It allows to configure the email verification through the `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION` setting variable, but it doesn't differentiate between normal and social signup. I would like to verify the email only when registering via normal signup, and don't verify it when it is submitted via social signup. Is it possible? how can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[it seems that the doc says](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

> `SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION` (=`ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION`)
>        As `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION`, but for social accounts.

if you set this one, django-allauth may do the difference when the user logs in

did you try it too ?

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one! I guess that's what I earned for working late night.